# Has the minimize speed been increased in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, window-management, minimize

In Ubuntu 12.10, by default, the minimize speed had been kept considerably slow in order to let users know where the window has minimized to...

but all of a sudden i noticed that now the speed is as normal as earlier versions! has there been an update that again increased this speed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The animation doesn't actually change according to the **minimize-speed-threshold**. Even when you change its value from **100** to **0**, the animation is still normal like what you encountered, @Nirmik. What I observe though is that if the **minimize-speed-threshold** is set to **100** (which is the default), and the **minimize-count** is set to **0** (also the default), the animation is slow just like when we first run 12.10 after upgrading/installing it.

Now, the animation will actually get faster every time you minimize a window, since the **minimize-count** will increase, and the larger it is the faster the animation. The increase in value of **minimize-count** will stop up to the value of the **minimize-speed-threshold**.

If you click on the **minimize-count**, you will see a description that says:

*This is used to adjust the animation speed by making it progressively faster the more it is used.*

For Slow Animation, I suggest to set up the following:

```
minimize-count = 0
minimize-fast-duration = 1000
minimize-slow-duration = 1000
minimize-speed-threshold = 0
```

For Faster Animation, I suggest to lower down the value of **minimize-fast-duration** and the **minimize-slow-duration**.

Comment: Amazingly awesome answer! Thanx! heres a +100 bounty for the excellent explaination!

Comment: And Canonical and ubuntu team...amazing logic! I loved it! the more you use,the more you are used to it and thus the speed can be increased! awesome thinking!

Comment: ...ill be allowed to grant the bounty after 23hrs...ill do it then and there ;)

Comment: I'm glad that helps you @Nirmik. One thing though, after restarting my computer, the minimize animation speed will get to normal from slow. And when checking it to the dconf-editor, the settings are the same, but you need to retype the values for the animation speed to take effect again. I don't know if you notice this. But that happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**  [According to OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-speed-up-ubuntu-12-10-minimize-animation), the minimize animation has been made slower.  They offer a solution as to how to restore old behavior, too:

> The tool we need to use to ‘edit’ the speed is called ‘dconf-editor‘
>   and can be be installed as part of the dconf-tools package.
>
> When installed launch it from the Dash by searching “dconf”
>
> When the Dconf-window opens expand the following sections of the
>   sidebar:
>
> **com > canonical**
>
> then click on (but don’t expand) the ‘unity’ entry.
>
> Select the following line in the main section of the window:
>
> **minimize-speed-threshold**
>
> Double-click on the value field (the number) to edit it.
>
> Change the value from ’100′ to ’0′.
>
> Changes take effect immediately.

I don't know why the animations seem to be back to normal... Maybe the animations reset themselves after the user has learned where apps go?  Lemme know if your minimize-speed-threshold is somehow at zero; I'm curious.

Comment: its still 100 but the animation is still faster than before!